# New vote orderings- default vote order is wrong

Tags: feature-request, sorting, answer-order

I've just noticed that the ordering of answers on questions has changed. Apparently you can now order answers by various criteria, which is fine.

But who the hell set "Active" as the default? It should clearly be votes. If voting people doesn't make their answer bubble to the top by default, this defeats the point of voting.

Comment: Hasn't this been the case for over a year?

Comment: Don't think so, I only just noticed that the ordering is wrong. Maybe the option has been there for a year but for some reason this setting just changed for me (I certainly didn't change it)

Comment: I wouldn't be so "certain" if I were you. :)

Comment: Answer ordering options **haven't changed in years**. Take into account that the order is sticky. Pick one ordering on one question, and it'll be used throughout the site whenever you open another question. If you never picked a setting, the default is still *Votes*.

Comment: @DeadMG: do you have keyboard shortcuts enabled? Did you happen to type `O`-`A` or `O`-`O` outside of a textbox by any chance? If so, type `O`-`V` to change the sort order back to votes. You probably didn't notice that you changed the sort order.

Comment: Who the hell? You.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I didn't even know this option existed until the default changed. Also, I'm not referring to the profile page, I mean the questions view.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: That question clearly refers to the profile page and not the page for a single question.

Comment: Yes, I thought you mean profile page. Still, answer here applies and there's a dupe, let me find it...

Comment: @gnat good find! Looked for it and couldn't find. :(

Comment: This answer doesn't apply, because I didn't sort by Active, and the answer states that I did. In fact, I'd literally never seen those buttons before I had a problem.

Comment: @DeadMG so you probably followed a link. For example [click this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248100/new-vote-orderings-default-vote-order-is-wrong?answertab=active#tab-top) and from now on, you'll have "active" sort on all answers here on MSE. Still, you clicked that link. Valid feature request or bug report would be "Possible XSRF attack changing my answer sorting - please fix". :-)

Answer (score 3):

These options have been available for a very long time, and the default is *Votes*. I cannot corroborate any change to this, recent or otherwise (confirmed using Incognito mode among, er, other ways).

You must have inadvertently clicked *Active* one day, or clicked on a dodgy link provided to you by some other SO user (with the `?answertab=active` querystring parameter in it). I wish people would stick to the "Share" links!!

Furthermore, remember that the choice is "sticky".

Comment: It can happen without clicking on any of those buttons. I hadn't even noticed any of those buttons until this happened to me. A mod's hypothesis was that a link from another user with that setting tacked on could have done it.

Comment: @muru: Ah, yes, that is a good possibility. Thanks.

Comment: Does that setting actually stick for any user that clicks on it? That must be a bug.

Comment: @DeadMG: Doesn't seem like a "bug" to me. There is a URL that sets the preference. When you give the URL to someone else and they visit the location, it sets _their_ preference. Although that being said it could be enhanced by removing the parameter from the querystring during the preference-setting procedure, which I would wildly support. I still wish people would use the share link or at least LOOK AT and UNDERSTAND URLs before they dish 'em out.

Comment: @Lightness: That would require that you actually visit a URL whose sole purpose is to set this setting, rather than visit a link to a question which also sets the setting.

Comment: @DeadMG Yeah it would be better if it were architected that way, I agree.

Comment: @DeadMG someone probably copied the URL with this and you didn't notice. Believe me, there is no code `if (user == "DeadMG") setAnswerTab("active");`.